# Retrieve Object containing only Active User Ids

Tags: arrays, object, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb

Still very new to dynamo db and elastic search.

So I have 2 tables.

Table 1: Contains items that I want to display
Table 2: Contains users that have an active column with a boolean. `{ active: true }`

What I want to do is retrieve all of the user ids that have `active: true`, and then retrieve the object from table 1 that contains all of those ids.

Step 1: Find the active users

```
let activeUsersResult = await es.search({
      index: userTable, //table2
      body: {
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": 
                    {
                      "match": { "active": "true" }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    })
```

This kind of worked. My table contains 8 active users, but it's only retrieving 7 active users. I was going to contact aws support for that fix, but an answer would be great from SO, but not the focus here.

Step 2: Get the active user ids

```
let activeIds = activeUsersResult.hits.hits.map( item => item._source.userId )
```

Which gives me an array of all of the active ids, which may look like:

```
activeIds = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', etc....]
```

Step 3: Get items object containing only those activeIds from table 1

Note: This es.search is also performing a search function

```
let itemsResult = await es.search({
        index: itemTable, //table 1
        body:{
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": e.searchQuery + "*",
                            "fields": ["item_name"]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                      "match": { "sold_out": "false" },
                      "match": { "userIds" : activeIds }
                    }
                  ]
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

The match line is where I'm having an issue. 
`"match": { "userIds" : activeIds }`

I need an array of objects that contain only those matching activeIds. I was hoping typing this out would give me ideas but I'm still lost.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `term` and `terms` query instead of match. When you require to match against an array you should use `terms` query. So your query should look like below.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": e.searchQuery + "*",
            "fields": [
              "item_name"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "sold_out": "false"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "userIds": activeIds
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Read about [term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) and [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query to understand more about how they work.

Comment: Thanks! So `term` works but `terms` isn't. I'm hard coding the array of ids for `activeIds` in case there's a different issue but it's returning an empty array. Any suggestions on what could be the issue?

Comment: `activeIds` should be an array of IDs and not comma separated string of IDs.

Comment: so instead of `const activeIds = ['123456', '123123', '123321', etc ]` it should be `const activeIds = [123456, 123123, 123321, etc ]` ?